# Making RSA encryption compatible in Python (PyCrypto) and PHP (OpenSSL)

Tags: php, python, encryption, rsa, pycrypto

I am migrating an entire PHP API, and while I used PyCrypto before, I am not sure how to translate the following encryption call, since I need the exact same result. The PHP call is:

```
define('KEY', "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQC81t5iu5C0JxYq5/XNPiD5ol3Z
w8rw3LtFIUm7y3m8o8wv5qVnzGh6XwQ8LWypdkbBDKWZZrAUd3lybZOP7/82Nb1/
noYj8ixVRdbnYtbsSAbu9PxjB7a/7LCGKsugLkou74PJDadQweM88kzQOx/kzAyV
bS9gCCVUguHcq2vRRQIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----");
$cypher = "";
$result = openssl_public_encrypt($plain, $cypher, KEY, OPENSSL_PKCS1_PADDING);
echo bin2hex($cypher);
```

Assuming everything goes right, this prints the content from `$cypher`, passed to hexadecimal. For a sample input `"azzzzzzzzzzzzdfdf"` I get something like: `"2281aeebc1166cdfb2f17a0a0775d927ca5a9ad999bae0e4954f58bd8082fdf7efe1fd284876530341f714456d7eb8cd44c57b20ab27029b84d5dc77a674bede3fe9065282931404286082e9df8607bdcff0818b90324dfee7d76b566d0f99bebc5cc913372c276ba373712128f1bcc226b59367cff93f7cdd6dbde25b366863"`.

I must assume this value as right, since the code was taken from an existing API I am migrating. However, trying the same with `PyCrypto` (yes, I am migrating the API to be available in Python), I use the following code:

```
def bin2hex(s):
    return "".join([hex(ord(c))[2:].zfill(2) for c in s])

KEY = """-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQC81t5iu5C0JxYq5/XNPiD5ol3Z
w8rw3LtFIUm7y3m8o8wv5qVnzGh6XwQ8LWypdkbBDKWZZrAUd3lybZOP7/82Nb1/
noYj8ixVRdbnYtbsSAbu9PxjB7a/7LCGKsugLkou74PJDadQweM88kzQOx/kzAyV
bS9gCCVUguHcq2vRRQIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----"""

from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_v1_5
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
encrypter = PKCS1_v1_5.new(RSA.importKey(KEY))
print bin2hex(encrypter.encrypt("azzzzzzzzzzzzdfdf"));
```

While I expect the same value be returned and printed, the value finally is `"3dd94ffabd01bb0e94010c0fedbcd4eb648f12e5d9e6d934b77ae86f76681d8a1b790cad9fddf6e6720415b4d645e525c33c402fa9778739b8e461790387e9508f7158a5fdc5723f5fc26d166b11a00759f0e0ee3ba6719a2e7c6b918f66e1311d1fff878ee2ca8762e1d6120f1e9585a76cdc7719ca20129ae76182b4277170"`.

Using `PKCS1_OAEP` outputs `"290f60f37088c2cb46ae9221b01ff46a463f270ef7cf70bbea49de0b5ae43aec34a0eb46e694cf22f689eb77e808c590fdc30eda09f9d3f3cb8c15e0505bf5a984c2a121bc9fa83c6b5ccf50235f072467b4ae9cdf0f0ee2e486626ffa62ad1aa715fbe29e8afe4ceab3ca5a5df4c1dc75d7f258285d7ff1f4f2b4dcb7a8413a"`.

It is easy to tell that I must fix my python code. How can I fix my python code so it returns the exact same result as the given PHP call?

Comment: Is `OPENSSL_PKCS1_PADDING` equivalent to `PKCS1_v1_5`?

Comment: This is the part I don't know and I need help with. Let me edit...

Comment: OPENSSL_PKCS1_PADDING is PKCS1_v1_5, and FWIW you should probably avoid using [because it has a known weakness](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/12688/can-you-explain-bleichenbachers-cca-attack-on-pkcs1-v1-5) that can be exploited in certain contexts.

Comment: It is not my choice. The PHP API is third party. However, If they are the same: what do their outputs differ?

Comment: https://phpseclib.com/docs/interop#rsa-decryption talks about interoperability between PHP and Python. It could use some expansion (OAEP and PKCS1 demos) but I think that whole page needs to be split out into multiple as is!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is fine. PKCS#1 v1.5 padding in pyCrypto is randomized ([source](https://github.com/dlitz/pycrypto/blob/v2.6.1/lib/Crypto/Cipher/PKCS1_v1_5.py#L135)). So the encryption will always be different even if you use the same key and plaintext. This is a desirable property.

If you want to check compatibility between pyCrypto and PHP's OpenSSL extension, then you would need to encrypt in one, decrypt in the other and check that you got what you expected.

---

PKCS#1 v1.5 padding should not be used nowadays, because there are efficient attacks against it. OAEP is a much better alternative.

Comment: *PKCS#1 v1.5 padding should not be used nowadays, because there are efficient attacks against it. OAEP is a much better alternative.* please tell me how to use OAEP in PHP so I can suggest the owners of the API. The API transfers quite sensitive data.

Comment: `OPENSSL_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING` should do it, but I don't know what the defaults are for the hash function and MGF1. In pyCrypto both are set to SHA-256 by default, but they can be freely changed. MGF1 can be set to SHA1, but the other should be set to SHA-256. Hold on, [here](http://php.net/manual/de/function.openssl-public-encrypt.php#118466) is some additional information.

Answer (score 1):

I've struggled with the same problem for quite long but finally managed to solve this.
The main issue was setting proper SHA hashes, in case of PHP's openssl_public_encrypt() it should be SHA1.

Here's the code for openssl_public_encrypt() with OPENSSL_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING:

```
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization, hashes
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import padding
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers import Cipher, algorithms, modes

def encrypt_key(message):
    with open('public_key', 'rb') as key_file:
        pub_key = key_file.read()
    public_key = load_pem_public_key(pub_key, default_backend())
    ciphertext = public_key.encrypt(
        message,
        padding.OAEP(
            mgf=padding.MGF1(algorithm=hashes.SHA1()),
            algorithm=hashes.SHA1(),
            label=None
            )
        )
    return ciphertext
```

basically a copy of [cryptography.io](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/rsa.html) documentation regarding RSA.