# openssl_public_encrypt in php corresponding to python public key encryption

Tags: python, php, encryption

I have implemented an python Django system which uses RSA public key encryption.When user makes an api request they need to encrypt the data using the public key and it is decrypted using private key in the python server side.

I was able to implement the system using angular where data encrypted in the angular side is successfully decrypted in the python server side.

Now we need to implement the same using php. But here I am facing an issue, because the data encrypted using the php was unable to decypted in the server side.

Error during decryption

> ValueError: Decryption Failed.

***This is  python code for encryption and decryption.***

```
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import padding
....
    public_key = ... #get the public key
    msg_in_bytes = str.encode(message) #string to byte conversion
    try:
        
        encrypted = public_key.encrypt(msg_in_bytes,padding.OAEP(mgf=padding.MGF1(algorithm=hashes.SHA256()),algorithm=hashes.SHA256(),label=None))
    except Exception as e: 
        logger.error(e)
......


private_key = .. #get the private key
    msg_in_bytes = b64decode(message) #Decode Base64 encoded string
    # print(msg_in_bytes)
    try:
        decrypted = private_key.decrypt(msg_in_bytes,padding.OAEP(mgf=padding.MGF1(algorithm=hashes.SHA256()),algorithm=hashes.SHA256(),label=None))
```

**And here is the PHP code**

```
json_data=...
openssl_public_encrypt($json_data, $encrypted, $public_key,OPENSSL_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING);
```

I am fairly new in PHP coding. Please help if there is any error in  php implementations.I assume that there is some issues in padding since python side has options to specify for the padding method while PHP side not.

I will not be able to change the python side code since it is working with angluar and other implementation too

Comment: That's because in `OPENSSL_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING` uses `MGF1-SHA1` instead of `MGF1-SHA256` and there is no way to set this in `openssl_public_encrypt` and in python you're using `MGF1-SHA256`. You'll need to change `MGF1-SHA256` to `MGF1-SHA1` in python. Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/q/35779799/2324206 https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-public-encrypt.php#118466

Comment: Thank you for your help, since we have some angular system working alongside with the python we will not be able to change the python side without affecting all of them. So can you suggest any other module in php where I can specify the MGF1-SHA256 which can be used in the place of openssl_public_encrypt

Comment: _phpseclib_ allows the specification of both digests (both default to SHA256): https://phpseclib.com/docs/rsa#encryption--decryption